# What is the difference between creating custom cell with xib method1 and method 2 below?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

Method 1
Select Cocoa Touch Class, select UITableViewCell with also create xib file.

Method 2
Select Cocoa Touch Class, select UITableViewCell without also create xib file. And then create empty view(xib) and xib's class to custom class.

With method 1, there is contentView.

[image]

With method 2, there is no contentView.

[image]

I wonder that method 2 adds subviews to cell.view or cell.contentView of cell?
I know method 1 adds subviews to contentView.

I am asking this because, with method 2, xib (custom view) covers the cell height. With method 1, contentView does not cover the cell height. (0,5 point less than)

Thank you.

Comment: You could just use the approach that suits your needs. :)

Comment: This is now the third time you have asked this question. Instead of posting duplicates over and over, please edit your original question as needed.

Comment: It is not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:

Will add subviews to cell's contentView.

Method 2:

There will be no contentView and all the subviews will be added directly to view.

If you use contentView it will position all subviews automatically when you are editing a cell..

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview

Comment: I swipe for delete for method and it works. Normally I should not work it if it adds subviews to cell view.

Comment: Try to put some content at the end of row and then do swipe to delete, If you are not using contentView your delete button will overlap the content.

Comment: Thabk you yasir.

Comment: You are welcome John :-)